# Different builds for different versions of iOS on App Store

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store

I want to target a particular version of Cordova for iPhone 4s, that is iOS 7.1.2 and Cordova version 5.4.1, and the rest use Cordova 6.2.0.

On the App Store, how do I go about having two builds for different versions of iOS?

Currently I have an **App Store version 1.0.6** ready for sale on the App Store using **Cordova 5.4.1**.

With my latest changes I have built again with **Cordova 5.4.1**. Then I've gone to my iTunes Connect and uploaded the build via Application Loader, created a new version (**1.0.7**) and select the newly-uploaded build.

Once the build is selected and review was successful, I then go to the "Pricing and Availability" section. Under "last compatible version settings", I've selected this version of the build as the last compatible version. Is this correct?

Building again with **Cordova 6.2.0** for the same app version (**1.0.7**), can I submit the build once again from Application Loader, submit it for review and then make it available in the App Store?

Comment: You can submit a version that targets earlier versions of iOS and then submit an update that targets later versions only.  In iTunes connect you can then nominate to keep the earlier version accessible for older devices, but you can no longer enhance that version.  Personally I wouldn't support devices earlier than iOS 8 or even iOS 9.  If you want to continue to enhance the version for older devices then you will need to release two separate apps

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you set the minimum iOS version for 6.2.0 to iOS 8 then users with older devices will still be able to download 1.0.7

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to submit v1.0.7 to iTunes Connect with the new version of Cordova since you can't have two versions of the app with the same version number. Increment the version number, then iTunes Connect will accept the new build.